# Compare 2 excel columns, the result will be compared to another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, string-comparison, worksheet-function, vba

I'm pretty new to vba, and I'm having a problem on comparison of two columns (all of the data under this 2 columns).

The workflow is, Column A compare to Column B with result to be put in Column C. Another column (Column D) will be used for comparison also (all of the columns are in 1 worksheet).

The logic would be like this:

Compare Column A to Column B

if Column B is blank, put "no value here"
if Column B has a value (sample value: PRODUCT-ID), compare B to column D (sample value:   PI, abbreviation of Product-id)
    if matched put "matched".
    if no matches, put "no match"

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you edit your post and give us some sample code?

Comment: Check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bexcel-vba%5D+compare+columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of VBA, here is a solution using formulas in the worksheet

in Column C we want to apply this rule:

```
IF B="" then 
    "NO VALUE HERE"
else
    IF B=D then
        "MATCHED"
    else
        "NOT MATCHED"
end if
```

you can do that with the below formula in column C (then filled down)

`=IF(B:B="","No Value Here",IF(B:B=D:D,"Matched","Not Matched"))`